# Git: Retrieve short commit hash for cache busting purposes

Tags: git, ubuntu-12.04, web-deployment

I want to use git hash's for cache busting purposes.

My deployment script would look for specific files in git, and would use the short version of the hash from the last commit where the file was changed. This means that the cache busting string for each file only changes when necessary.

So far I have the following command, which is close but not quite right:

```
git log -n 1 --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline htdocs/js/sample.js
```

which returns:

```
21b1991 Commit message here
```

I could parse that string for the commit hash, but I'd rather not do that if possible.

I would like to make git return:

```
21b1991
```

I'd certainly like the solution to continue working should git start returning a different length hash upon issuing the command. I'm also not too against using the full hash, but I don't feel that will be necessary.

The deployment will be git based, and taking place on an Ubuntu 12.04 TLS system.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `--pretty=format:%h` instead of `--abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline`

E.g.

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h htdocs/js/sample.js
```

Comment: Work exactly as I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this:

```
git log -n 1 --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline htdocs/js/sample.js | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that the short commit hash can vary in size, depending on how many commits you have in your history -- the price you pay for using the full hash in your code is small, while with the full hash you are assured of always referring to the correct file.

I look at the short hash as a convenience for us poor small-brained developers, not something that program code should use to save a few bytes.

Comment: That isn't a problem, and the marked answer will always return the entire short hash.

Comment: The only criteria the hash needs to meet is a low probability of duplication between commits of a specific file. The short hash seems to be perfectly suitable, unless you have maths that proves otherwise.

Comment: Additionally, the short code returned by git is guaranteed to be unique (at the time of execution) even if git has to return the entire sha1 string to achieve this. See http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html

Comment: "2 digits should be enough for the current year", anyone? (See -- Y2K bug.) The short hash is long enough at the time of execution, but is not guaranteed to be long enough forever. I'm just sayin'.

Comment: Lets say git gives me a short hash of a289b for a particular commit. In the unlikely scenario that another commit of the same file begins with a289b then git will, at the time of deployment for the new commit, return a short hash with an additional character such as a289bd. This means that the string intended for use as a cache busting parameter during deployment will always be unique. That's the important aspect.